# jQuery - replace line break <br /> with new line \n

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I am using jQuery 1.11.

I have a string displayed in html and I want that same string copied and pasted to a textarea.

The problem for me is that the string to be pasted contains a line break `<br />`. To correctly display the string in the textarea, I must replace the line break `<br />` with a new line `\n`.

I am using `replace`, but each permutation I write to replace the `<br />` with the `\n` fails. The string is printed along one line.

I have searched google & SO, but this just does not work for me - I am missing something basic here.

How can I write a string replace function to replace the `<br />` with `\n`?

Here is my string:

```
[employer]<br />[mm/yyy] - [mm/yyy] - ([number] years1, [number] months)<br /><br />
```

Here is the replace code that does not work for me:

```
var text = $(this).closest('.employment_history_suggestion_add_button').prev().text();  // Get text of the previous span element
text = text.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n");  // replace line break with new line for correct display in textarea.
```

**EDIT**

**This is the code that now works.**

I was using the `.text()` - should have been using the `.html()`.

I was using `\\n` - should have been using `\n`.

```
var text = $(this).closest('.employment_history_suggestion_add_button').prev().html();  // Get html of the copied string (keep the line breaks for replacing with new lines).
text = text.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gim, "\\n");
$('#id_employment_history_employerTA').val(function (i, oldVal) {
                return oldVal + text;  // append the value of text to the textarea.
});
```

I hope that this helps someone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unclear which part of your code is failing, although you'll want to double escape the `\n` carriage return in your replace pattern:

```js
var text = '[employer]<br />[mm/yyy] - [mm/yyy] - ([number] years1, [number] months)<br /><br />'

text = text.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gim, "\\n")
alert(text);
```

**Result:**

```
[employer]\n[mm/yyy] - [mm/yyy] - ([number] years1, [number] months)\n\n
```

Comment: l'L'l, thanks your code helped me alot. How do I display the `text` in the textarea with the newlines `\n` as new lines and not as text. This is how the text displays: `[employer]\n[mm/yyy] - [mm/yyy] - ([number] years1, [number] months)\n\n`. But I want the `\n` as actual new lines. I have placed an edit in the OP.

Comment: If you don't want the literal `\n` then you would remove one of the backslashes in the replace pattern (so instead of `\\n` you would only use `\n`). What part of your code was failing before? Your pattern should've worked for the most part; the multi-line modifier `m` after the pattern might've been what you needed also :)

Comment: l'L'l, thanks all working now. I understand this now. Thanks again.